# Duplicate Instance ID Error when Upgrading TFS 2012 to 2015 with duplicate TFS collection DB

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

How can I attach both a TFS collection database and a COPY of the same database (for Archive reasons) to the the same TFS server? Or how can I change a specific database "Instance ID"?

In the process of upgrading from Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2012 to 2015, I am getting an error when the upgrade wizard performs the readiness check: TF400313: The following databases have duplicate instance.

There are in fact two instances of a TFS collection database (tfs_SQA, tfs_SQA_Archive), both restored from the same backup file, but named differently.  According to the log, it appears both databases have the same "Instance ID" guid.  If I delete the archive copy, the error goes away.

How can I get around this error? Is it possible to change the "Instance ID"?  Is there a TFS utility or command that will fix this?

**From the TFS upgrade log file:**

```
 The following database has a duplicate instance ID: 08c5382e...
 The host name is Tfs_SQA.   
 The following database has a duplicate instance ID: 08c5382e... 
 The host name is Tfs_SQA_Archive.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TFSConfig` to change the ID with the `[ChangeServerId][1]` option.

You can use it with the `/ProjectCollectionsOnly` flag to only alter the project collection databases.

Note: I have never tried this before with two databases with duplicate IDs attached, so do so at your own risk.

It's also worth noting, however, that there is a `Collection` option that allows you to clone a Team Project Collection safely, which is probably what you actually want to do:

https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#collection